# Comparing two datetime columns in data frame and return a flag

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare two date-time columns in a dataframe and create a new column that returns a 0/1 flag.

Dataframe:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|       Date1       |       Date2       |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| 6-8-2020 13:27:01 | 6-8-2020 13:14:04 |
| 6-8-2020 5:01:02  | 7-8-2020 8:00:25  |
| 6-8-2020 7:45:43  | 6-8-2020 8:10:04  |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The condition is: if date1 > date2 then 1 else 0

Wanted result from the example dataframe above:

```
+------+
| Flag |
+------+
|    1 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
+------+
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes first, compare and convert `True, False` values to `1, 0` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.Date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date1, dayfirst=True)
df.Date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.Date2, dayfirst=True)
df['Flag'] = (df.Date1 > df.Date2).astype(int)
print (df)
                Date1               Date2  Flag
0 2020-08-06 13:27:01 2020-08-06 13:14:04     1
1 2020-08-06 05:01:02 2020-08-07 08:00:25     0
2 2020-08-06 07:45:43 2020-08-06 08:10:04     0
```

Or use for compare [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and for `1,0` [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Flag'] = df.Date1.gt(df.Date2).view('i1')
```